# Ubuntu Server only using a portion of the screen

Tags: server, display-resolution

[image: Ubuntu Server]

I daily drive an Ubuntu Server with i3 with 4 monitors. It works really fine, but for some odd reason at random times all 4 monitors start outputting the same thing and the screen resolution shrinks down a lot.

Usually, a format and re-install would fix this. (It has happened 3 times before). But now, even the installation of ubuntu server has the same problem.

This isn't a problem with other flavors of ubuntu. When I installed GUI Ubuntu, my resolution was fine and all 4 monitors worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't really an answer, but I removed my DVI monitor cable from my 4th  monitor. And everything just worked again.

I then reconnected my 4th monitor and everything is going good. I'll update here the next time the issue happens.